# Understanding a proof in Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, proof-explanation

I am not getting a step in simple inductive proof in Lie Algebra: it is below. **Theorem 2.6** I have copies just for knowing hypothesis; for this, a proposition is used, and my question is about understanding a step in it.

*What is not getting:* It is defined that 
$$x_i=(ad y-\beta1)^ix\in L.$$ Then in the expansion of $r+1$th power, see the term after binomial coefficient: it is written $\rho(x_i)$. I am not understanding this; whether this should be $x_i$ or $\rho(x_i)$? This could be very easy, but I am new in Lie algebra. Please help me.

Thanks for the patience and in advance for help!

> [image]

---

Comment: This is in Lie Algebras of Finite and Affine Type - Carter, page 17.

Comment: So is this correct: in the equation before proof  of proposition, in LHS, we replace $x$ by $\rho(x)$ and also in RHS, we replace $x$ by $\rho(x)$; is this OK?

Comment: Note that $x_i$ acts by multiplication so really it is the same as $\rho $. This is a bit of a screwy thing that people in representation theory do but it's just repackaging notation, that's all.

Comment: I am partially getting your point; but is it ok what I said in my earlier comment? I mean, doing this correction, will it be ok?

Comment: Yes on the left hand side, right hand side is a bit less clear to me because of the $\operatorname{ad} $ mucking things up. You probably could but you'd have to lift the $\operatorname{ad} $ to $\rho$ in the obvious way.